# What would be more efficient for speed modulo or if statement?

Tags: java

Which would would be better the fastest solution to wrap an index around a range  if im calling the code many times in a loop?

```
int length = 4;
int firstIndex = 4;
int lastIndex = 7;
int currIndex = 4;

// Example 1 (if statement)
    // Incrementing currIndex
        if (++currIndex > lastIndex)
            currIndex = firstIndex;
    // Decrementing currIndex
        if (--currIndex < firstIndex)
            currIndex = lastIndex

// Example 2 (Modulo)
    // Incrementing currIndex
        currIndex = firstIndex + (++currIndex % length);
    // Decrementing currIndex
        currIndex = firstIndex + ((--currIndex + length) % length);
```

Comment: Examples 1 and 2 don't appear to be doing the same thing.  It's a bit like asking us whether apples or oranges taste better.

Comment: Sorry startIndex should have been firstIndex in the modulo example

Comment: Very likely this is [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize), and there will be very little difference between the two. If you really need to know, then only testing can tell you which is better after JIT has done it's work. I would suggest you stick with the code that better shows the *intent* of the code, which would be example 1.

Comment: A modulo-operation is very slow. An if is most likely to be faster than a modulo and more readable.

Comment: Actually, the modulo code doesn't work. It *happens* by chance to work for the particular values given, but change the upper or lower bound will make it fail to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are likely so close it doesn't matter in practice. If you really want to find out, wrap each approach in a loop that does it 100,000 or 1M times and time it.

My guess is the "if" statements will be faster. It's only one add, and a couple compare and branch statements which are "cheap" instructions in a processor. The modulus requires at least as many statements, but more expensive ones.